# How can I leverage CDN with my AngularJS app on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, cdn

I have an `MVC` project which really just serves an `angular` application. This will be a public application and I expect it to get a lot of traffic, so I'm trying to use a `CDN` to keep requests to my servers light.

I've found many articles on how to get `angular` itself from a `CDN` but what I'm looking for is for MY file (`css`, `html`, `js`, `media`) to get served from a `CDN`. So for example, if I have a `directive`, then the template would need to be served from a `CDN`, but I can't hard-code it because the template may not have been uploaded to the test or prod environments yet.

**Update:** The MVC application only serves the initial layout and home pages. Once my angular script loads MVC isn't really used anymore. The back-end is a separate Web API application.

Answer (score 1):

You might be asking the wrong question, but you're on the right track for how to optimize for high traffic.

First, learn how to serve the angular application as static files. On a past project I worked on I had two projects in my visual studio solution, one was a Web API back-end, and the other was a web project that just served static content. You can configure Visual Studio to run both projects at the same time on different ports from localhost. This doesn't answer your question, but setting up dev like this will get you a step closer.

Next, once you know your project's front-end and back-end are decoupled from the server level, make sure you're not going to get an CORS issues from cross-domain requests. If you're going to be serving your back-end from a subdomain, CORS may be an issue. Look into that, you'll probably need to add some code to your MVC app to solve that problem.

Now that you've got all that figured out, find out how to use a CDN service. There are many offerings with specifics of how to deploy content and SSL certificates varying for each. Amazon Web Services, Microsoft Azure, and many others offer CDN services, but before you even look at that stuff, make sure you can actually serve your back-end from a different port on your dev machine and it still works.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to make that explicit but my app is split exactly as you described already. The only thing served directly by MVC is the layout and home page, which only load the scripts. But every other file is just a static file. And the back-end is a Web API service hosted on a separate application, CORS is no longer an issue there.

Comment: In that case, pick a CDN and ask your question again if their documentation doesn't help you.  Procedures for every CDN is a little different.  You also might just need static hosting like azure blob storage of Amazon S3 without the cost of a CDN in front of it. It still offloads the connection from your server without the nuisance or managing cached files on the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to think of a good solution to this recently...
In local testing (grunt serve), i use the current non-minified .js/.css file, but when creating a build (grunt build), Id want to point those files to the CDN in  my Angular project.
I'm thinking for your grunt(gulp/webpack/etc) build (which creates the minified local files for the build), you could make a task to prepend certain urls/files to your CDN via
https://github.com/callumlocke/grunt-cdnify or https://github.com/tactivos/grunt-cdn (but it would still use your non-minified files for grunt serve).

It would be cool if uploading to CDN and invalidating the files was a grunt/gulp/webpack plugin.
Then you could automate it as part of your prod builds. 
Guessing your build system like Jenkins/etc would upload your app to wherever.
and then either with a grunt/gulp plugin like so could invalidate your files:
https://github.com/keycdn/grunt-keycdn if you use that CDN service.
I am guessing your build system like Jenkins could also do this work for you via its own CDN upload/invalidation plugins.

I know this answer is mentioning grunt specifically, but there should be similar plugins for gulp/webpack/etc as well.